# Xcode 4.3 documentation search: inexplicable missing result

Tags: xcode, search, documentation, nsurlconnection, organizer

I've upgraded from Xcode 4.2.1 to Xcode 4.3 on two Macs now. I ran into a curious problem: when searching the documentation for "NSURLConnection" through Organizer, the only result returned is NSURLConnectionDelegate, not NSURLConnection itself.

The search parameters are as follows:

Match type: **Contains**
Doc Sets: **Mac OS X 10.7 Core Library** and **Xcode 4.3 Developer Library**
Languages: **All languages**

I can manually browse the documentation to get to NSURLConnection, so the class reference for it is present and accounted for, but it's not showing up in a search.

Same thing happens if I search for "NSURL". Over 200 results, but NSURLConnection is not among them. Upper or lower case, makes no difference. If I enable the iOS 5 doc set, NSURLConnection isn't shown there either, but NSURLConnectionDelegate does get shown twice, as you'd expect.

On the first Mac, I installed 4.3 while 4.2.1 was still installed, so it didn't redownload any documentation. I thought this might have something to do with it, so on the second Mac, I purged all traces of 4.2.1 from the Mac first: `uninstall-devtools --mode=all` followed by  `rm -r /Library/Developer`. I then downloaded the doc sets in Xcode 4.3 once it was installed, but no, NSURLConnection is still missing from the results.

I have no idea what other documentation, if any, is not being caught by the search. Am I missing something really obvious, is there a documentation bug, is the search index broken or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was a documentation bug. Xcode just downloaded and installed an updated set of docs, and NSURLConnection is now found when searching.